# PREPARE_URL Function in APEX; Linking a modal dialog

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I have an issue using modal dialogs in APEX (version: 18.1.0.00.45). I am trying to create a link button in HTML as a part of the "Static Content" and ended up with following:

`<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='f?p=200:3:&APP_SESSION.::::P3_VALUE1,P3_VALUE2,P3_VALUE3:2,&P2_OUTPUT.,17';">Text</button>`.

It works just fine with normal pages. But with modal dialog I get a following error:

> Application 200 Dialog page 3 can not be played back successfully.
>   Make sure that the template used on page 3 has the type "dialog page"
>   and the corresponding code is defined to initialize, close and cancel
>   the JavaScript dialog.

Security of this page is defined in the same way as on other pages.

As far as I know there is a possibility to use PREPARE_URL Function. But I have no idea how to do it in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer I have bookmarked for this problem, though only need it once in a blue moon.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4034653

It basically generates the link on render, but it depends exactly how you want to use it.

Comment: Oh nice! Thank you!